# TortoiseHg 3.3 "Failed to open path in terminal"

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, vista64

I'm using the 64-bit version of TortoiseHg 3.3 on Windows Vista64, and when I navigate to the `Repository` --> `Terminal` I get the following error:

[image: TortoiseHg Failed to Open path in terminal]

I guess that I need to change a setting somewhere, and I do not know where to look.

I did navigate to C:\Windows\System32 and found that cmd.exe DOES exist in this directory so it seems to be that the `/K title globalspiritualevents` part is failing.

I also found that I can change the shell by opening `Settings` clicking `TortoiseHg` and changing the selection in the dropdown box for `Shell` on the right hand side.

I know that it is possible to navigate to the project root in a terminal window and start running `hg` commands, but TortoiseHg makes it more convenient.

What do I need to do to get the terminal to work from the TortoiseHg menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this.  It seems to be a bug in 3.3.  If you change the `Shell` in File, Settings, TortoiseHg and use the same command with *forward* slashes, or *double* backslashes, it works:

```
c:/windows/system32/cmd.exe /k title %(reponame)s
```

or

```
c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /k title %(reponame)s
```

It also works with the following since `cmd.exe` is in the path anyway:

```
cmd.exe /k title %(reponame)s
```